# how to limit a column in oracle to support only character?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i need to create a table which has number of columns in which one column is varchar2 type.Now the problem is i need to set that particular column should support only alphabets.
I've tried this code but this didn't get work can anybody help me!

thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TABLE test_1
(
  test_id number,
  test_name varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT name_test
  CHECK (test_name where regexp_like(test_name,'^([aA-zZ])+$'))
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, just use the function(which returns true/false).

```
CREATE TABLE z_test_1
(
  test_id number,
  test_name varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT name_test
  CHECK (regexp_like(test_name,'^([aA-zZ])+$'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE test_1
(
  test_id number,
  test_name varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT
    name_test
    CHECK (
      regexp_like(test_name,'^([aA-zZ])+$')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_regular_expressions_constraints_updates_columns.htm

```
...CHECK (regexp_like(test_name,'^[[:alpha:]]+$') )
```